# Делегирование событий в изображениях

Tags: javascript, css, html5

У меня есть flexbox, в котором хранятся изображения и их описание. Как мне на JS можно обыграть так, чтобы по клику на изображение (у каждого есть атрибут с уникальным номером) открывалось модальное окно, в котором показано именно то изображение, на которое я кликнул и его описание где-нибудь снизу. Модальное окно я сделал и оно успешно открывается. Почитал в интернете, что мне необходимо использовать делегирование событий, но я хочу понять сам принцип работы, и пока у меня не очень получается. Я, конечно, могу создать много модальных окон, каждое из которых будет хранить в себе изображение с уникальным id, но я уверен,что это будет лишним, т.к есть решение куда лучше с наименьшим кол-вом строк кода. Ещё было бы очень классно, если бы мне подсказали принцип работы перемотки таких изображений на подобие слайдера в попапе. Спасибо!

```
<div class="images__wrapper">
    <div class="images__container">
        <div data-id="01" class="images-container__item" onclick="showModalWindow()">
            <img src="img/dormitory/main-building.jpg" class="images-container-item__img" alt="Изображение 1">
            <div class="images-container-item__caption">Описание 1</div>
            </div>
        <div data-id="02" class="images-container__item" onclick="showModalWindow()">
            <img src="img/dormitory/hall.jpeg" class="images-container-item__img" alt="Изображение 2">
            <div class="images-container-item__caption">Описание 2</div>
            </div>
        <div data-id="03" class="images-container__item" onclick="showModalWindow()">
            <img src="img/dormitory/kitchen.jpeg" class="images-container-item__img" alt="Изображение 3">
            <div class="images-container-item__caption">Описание 3</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="images__popup hide__modal__window" id="images-popup">
    <div class="images__popup__container">
        <div class="images-popup-cont__block">
            <div class="images__popup__close" onclick="showModalWindow()">&#10006;</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

function showModalWindow() {
    const modal = document.querySelector('#images-popup');
    const bodyScroll = document.querySelector('#images-body');

    if (modal.classList.contains('hide__modal__window')) {
        modal.classList.remove('hide__modal__window');
        modal.classList.add('show__modal__window');
    } else {
        modal.classList.add('hide__modal__window');
        modal.classList.remove('show__modal__window');
    }

    if (modal.classList.contains('show__modal__window')) {
        bodyScroll.classList.add('body__no-scroll');
        bodyScroll.classList.remove('body__scroll');
    } else {
        bodyScroll.classList.remove('body__no-scroll');
        bodyScroll.classList.add('body__scroll');
    }
}

.images__wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    padding-top: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}
.images__container {
    width: 98%;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
}
.images-container__item {
    width: 350px;
    height: 250px;
    margin: 10px 10px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    color: #eee;
    cursor: default;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
.images-container__item img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
.images-container__item img:hover {
    transform: scale(1.1);
    transition: .2s linear;
}
.images-container__item:hover > 
    .images-container-item__caption {
    transition: .3s linear;
    opacity: 1;
}
.images-container-item__caption {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    pointer-events: none;
    opacity: 0;
    background-color: #641ec5;
    width: 100%;
}
.images__popup {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 99;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.show__modal__window {
    display: block;
}
.hide__modal__window {
    display: none;
}
.images__popup__close {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    color: #eee;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #641ec5;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 20px;
    top: -10px;
    right: -10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.images__popup__close:hover {
    background-color: #eee;
    border: 2px solid #641ec5;
    color: #641ec5;
    transition: background-color .3s linear;
}
.images__popup__container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}
.images-popup-cont__block {
    width: 70%;
    height: 80%;
    display: flex;
    background-color: #eee;
    position: relative;
}

const imageFinal = document.createElement("img");
imageFinal.setAttribute("src", imgSrc.src);
imageFinal.setAttribute("alt", imgSrc.alt);
const contentPopup = document.querySelector('.popup-cont-block__content');
contentPopup.appendChild(imageFinal);
contentPopup.innerHTML = imgSrc;

const contentPopup = document.querySelector('.popup-cont-block__content');
contentPopup.appendChild(imgSrc);
contentPopup.innerHTML = imgSrc;
```

Comment: Добавьте свой пример. Про делегирование можно тут почитать https://habr.com/ru/post/512782/  и тут https://learn.javascript.ru/event-delegation

Comment: Внёс изменение - добавил код моего примера

Comment: А где стили? почитали ссылки? - так же ничего не понятно

Comment: Добавил стили, ссылки читаю

Comment: разобрались в делегирование?

Comment: Спасибо за ресурс, более менее начал что-то понимать! Но мозг до сих пор не может выстроить логическую цепочку событий для вывода нужного изображения.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> но я хочу понять сам принцип работы, и пока у меня не очень получается.

Вот смотрите, смысл в том что прослушивание вешается на общий блок, где располагаются элементы. В данном случае это `images__wrapper`. Далее должны сделать проверку, что если мы кликнули по изображению, тогда что-то делаем - вы хотите получить данные элементов

Пример:

```js
const images = document.querySelector('.images__wrapper') // нашли область всех фото
images.addEventListener('click', function({
  target
}) {
  if (target.classList.contains('images-container-item__img')) {
    let imgSrc = target.src // нашли ссылку изображения
    let itemBlok = target.closest('.images-container__item') // нашли родителя
    let itemTitle = itemBlok.querySelector('.images-container-item__caption').textContent // нашли описание
    console.log(imgSrc)
    console.log(itemTitle)
  }
})
```

```css
.images__wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-top: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.images__container {
  width: 98%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.images-container__item {
  width: 350px;
  height: 250px;
  margin: 10px 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: #eee;
  cursor: default;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.images-container__item img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.images-container__item img:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  transition: .2s linear;
}

.images-container__item:hover>.images-container-item__caption {
  transition: .3s linear;
  opacity: 1;
}

.images-container-item__caption {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0;
  background-color: #641ec5;
  width: 100%;
}

.images__popup {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 99;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.show__modal__window {
  display: block;
}

.hide__modal__window {
  display: none;
}

.images__popup__close {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: #eee;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #641ec5;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  top: -10px;
  right: -10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.images__popup__close:hover {
  background-color: #eee;
  border: 2px solid #641ec5;
  color: #641ec5;
  transition: background-color .3s linear;
}

.images__popup__container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

.images-popup-cont__block {
  width: 70%;
  height: 80%;
  display: flex;
  background-color: #eee;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="images__wrapper">
  <div class="images__container">
    <div data-id="01" class="images-container__item">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1657299156791-44140a28a518?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1170&q=80" class="images-container-item__img" alt="Изображение 1">
      <div class="images-container-item__caption">Описание 1</div>
    </div>
    <div data-id="02" class="images-container__item">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1657299156791-44140a28a518?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1170&q=80" class="images-container-item__img" alt="Изображение 2">
      <div class="images-container-item__caption">Описание 2</div>
    </div>
    <div data-id="03" class="images-container__item">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1657299156791-44140a28a518?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1170&q=80" class="images-container-item__img" alt="Изображение 3">
      <div class="images-container-item__caption">Описание 3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Далее эти данные нужно использовать в вашем попапе. Думаю у вас должно получится.

**P.S** бы очень классно, если бы мне подсказали принцип работы перемотки таких изображений -- думаю пока рубеж делегирования, а потом подумаете а слайдах ))

Comment: Уже стыдно обращаться,  но ничего не остаётся. У меня не получается вывести данные в попап. Я попробовал appendChild - не выходит, я пробовал createElement(img) и присваивать ему  уже готовую переменную imgSrc, чтобы потом добавить как узел, но всё равно не получается. Через innerHTML удалось вывести описание, но с изображением промах :(

Comment: Добавьте свои попытке, в ваш вопрос, я посмотрю - позже отвечу

Comment: Я попытался сейчас восстановить код после моих вчерашних тщетных попыток вывести изображение.

Comment: Вечером посмотрю или завтра и отвечу

Comment: Спасибо за то, что уделяете время и пытаетесь помочь. У меня появилась идея как это можно обыграть, сейчас буду реализовывать. Если получится - отпишу)

Comment: Спасибо за уделённое мне время, у меня всё получилось, я смог разобраться, моя идея сработала

Comment: @TheKunichka рад за вас )) удачи

Comment: Если долго мучиться - что-нибудь получится))
Ещё раз спасибо!